# Forward fastcgi STDERR to nginx error log

Tags: perl, nginx, cgi

I'm using nginx with a [fastcgi-wrapper](http://nginxlibrary.com/downloads/perl-fcgi/fastcgi-wrapper) from http://nginxlibrary.com/perl-fastcgi/ to execute perl files on ubuntu 14.04. My problem is that whenever an error occurs in the perl file, the nginx error log contains no descriptive insides (unlike Apache). There is only a generic error like "upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream".

I assume that STDERR is not forwarded properly but I couldn't find any hint how to configure the wrapper in order to get it working as desired. Does anyone has some ideas for me?

Comment: What's `tied(*STDERR)` and `eval { fileno(*STDERR) } // "u"`? (I'm assuming you're using Perl 5.10+)

Comment: I printed the results of your statements and the first one returns nothing whereas the second one says 2.

Comment: Did you do that in the wrapper? Sorry, I wasn't clear. Could you do this within the `Accept` loop in the wrapper.

Comment: Ok, I tried to print it from the loop into a log file but without success. But I realized that the perl error messages are printed in the terminal I used to restart the services (perl-fcgi and nginx). Maybe this helps you in some way. Additionally I realized that the service does not stop properly with `sudo service perl-fcgi stop` It says "perl no process found" and when I start the service it says "bind/listen address already in use". Is there a better way to run perl with nginx?

Comment: Re "Ok, I tried to print it from the loop into a log file but without success", Well, we can skip diagnosing why it doesn't work and work around the problem by opening STDERR to write to your own log file instead of using nginx's, but you just said you couldn't figure out how to write to a file!?

Comment: I thought about that, too. Problem is that I can open a file for stderr in the wrapper and if I force an entry by `print $fh_stderr "foobar"`, the content is visible in the file but all other error messages keep appearing in the shell which I used to start the perl-cgi service.

Comment: I put the redirection statement at the top of the wrapper-script as well as in the request_loop sub right before the while loop. I assume that the FCGI Socket has kind of "stolen" stderr and it is not reachable from the script any more (daemon/child-process/???). Is this possible?

Comment: I specified the information I'd need to answer that.

Comment: You did and I'm very thankful for your time helping me. I incorporated your two statements in the request_loop and printed the result into a file. The result identical to the variation where I did it in the Perl/CGI script. The tied statement returns "" (nothing) and the fileno statement returns "2". I found another FCGI Daemon on CPAN - FCGI::Daemon. It's documentation mentions that my wrapper is not forwarding STDERR to the server log. Unfortunately I cannot get it working on ubuntu 14.04. I get the impression nginx is not meant for proper perl development.

Comment: Just use `open(STDERR, '>>', $log_file)`. If you do that, you should probably pass a dummy handle to `FCGI::Request()` instead of STDERR.

Comment: We use FCGI::Daemon to run scripts in the FCGI deamon process itself (which is different than what you said you wanted to do). We had to make a lot of fixes. (The "master" branch of [this git repo](https://github.com/ikegami/perl-FCGI-Daemon) has the fixed version. Patches not submitted to the author yet.)

Comment: Thank you for the link to your repo. I installed the wrapper, generated the required *ph files but now when I start the service or the Daemon directly with `sudo perl /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/FCGI/Daemon.pm` I get the error message `Error - Unable to set RLIMIT_AS` and next line says `permission denied` Do you have another advice for me?

Comment: Just remove the checks. Make sure to read the license, though. "Notwithstanding any other provision of this License, if you modify the
Program, your modified version must prominently offer all users
interacting with it remotely through a computer network (if your version
supports such interaction) an opportunity to receive the Corresponding
Source of your version by providing access to the Corresponding Source
from a network server at no charge, through some standard or customary
means of facilitating copying of software."

Comment: It's up and running - thanks for your support. I'll check the license for our usecase.